# How to make CSS animation-delay larger than animation-duration?

Tags: html, css, animation

i can't find answer for my question in a web.
Here is big trouble witch i doesn't understand: Why i can't set in CSS code *animation-delay* property larger than *animation-duration* property. Although I can definitely, but animation start's working wrong.

**Here is my keyframes:**

```
@keyframes transfom-welcome-button-in {
from {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    opacity: 0;
}
to {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

}

**Here is my button CSS code:**

```
.welcomeLayer .button {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    animation-name: transfom-welcome-button-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

**Above code is work good, but if i'll change code like this. The button is initially not hiding, and the animation somehow twitches:**

```
.welcomeLayer .button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    animation-name: transfom-welcome-button-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s; /*0.6s, 0.7s,...,0.ns*/
}
```

Why i cant set *animation-delay* larger than *animation-delay*??? Please help!

Comment: Perhaps you could make an example in a JSiddle.net demo but you should set the opacity to 0 in the base CSS of the class.

Comment: I forgot to put opacity here. Fix. I'll try to make demo.

Comment: please post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Button must be hidden until animation-duration time + animation-delay time is finished.

Comment: I make a demo, but it doesn't working there at all http://jsfiddle.net/2mnd0rho/